# Matching and capturing multiple RegEx statements

Tags: regex, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm running the below on a 2008 R2 file server to extract quota info since the PS FSRM module isn't available. When matching the strings in the `$RegEx` variable, it works fine as long as there's only 2 strings in the variable, and the `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]` values are added as expected to the object array, but when I try to add a 3rd capture, or in this case 5 captures, I get no output at all. Nothing in `$matches` and nothing in `$objArr`.

```
$RegEx = 'Quota Path:\s+(.*)[\s\S]*?' +
         'Source Template:\s+(.*)\s+' +
         'Limit:\s+(.*)\s+' +
         'Used:\s+(.*)\s+' +
         'Available:\s+(.*)'
$objArr = @()

$objArr = (dirquota qu l | Out-String) -replace '\r\n', "`n" -split '\n\n' |
          where {$_ -match $RegEx} |
          foreach {
            New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property ([ordered]@{
              QuotaPath  = $matches[1]
              Template   = $matches[2]
              QuotaLimit = $matches[3]
              Used       = $matches[4]
              Availble   = $matches[5]
            })
          }
```

What I don't understand is I can rearrange the captures and any combination of 2 will work, so it seems the capture strings are correct to some degree, but as soon as I try to add a 3rd or more, I get nothing. I'm sure I'm missing something with the way the RegEx capture strings are formatted.

The `dirquota qu l | Out-String` outputs a string as follows:

```
...

Quota Path:             E:\DirA\SubdirA\SubdirA1
Share Path:             \\SERVER\SubdirA\SubdirA1
                        \\SERVER\E\DirA\SubdirA\SubdirA1
                        \\SERVER\DirA\SubdirA\SubdirA1
Source Template:        TemplateA (Matches template)
Quota Status:           Enabled
Limit:                  500.00 MB (Hard)
Used:                   6.00 KB (0%)
Available:              499.99 MB
Peak Usage:             6.00 KB (4/1/2015 12:27 PM)
Thresholds:
   Warning ( 80%):      Event Log
   Limit (100%):        Event Log

Quota Path:             E:\DirB\SubdirB\SubdirB1
Share Path:             \\SERVER\SubdirB\SubdirB1
                        \\SERVER\E\DirB\SubdirB\SubdirB1
                        \\SERVER\DirB\SubdirB\SubdirB1
Source Template:        TemplateB (Matches template)
Quota Status:           Enabled
Limit:                  500.00 MB (Hard)
Used:                   1.00 KB (0%)
Available:              500.00 MB
Peak Usage:             1.00 KB (7/12/2016 12:09 PM)
Thresholds:
   Warning ( 80%):      Event Log
   Limit (100%):        Event Log

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not getting the desired results because your regular expression simply doesn't match. There's an additional line between the `SourceTemplate` and `Limit` record that your modified regular expression doesn't account for:

```
...
Quota Path:             E:\DirA\SubdirA\SubdirA1
Share Path:             \\SERVER\SubdirA\SubdirA1
                        \\SERVER\E\DirA\SubdirA\SubdirA1
                        \\SERVER\DirA\SubdirA\SubdirA1
Source Template:        TemplateA (Matches template)
Quota Status:           Enabled
Limit:                  500.00 MB (Hard)
Used:                   6.00 KB (0%)
Available:              499.99 MB
...
```

The `Source Template:\s+(.*)\s+` part of your regular expression matches the (sub)string "Source Template:" followed by one or more whitespace characters (`\s+`), a grouped match of all characters up to (but not including) the next newline (`(.*)`), and again one or more whitespace characters (`\s+`). However, since the next part of your regular expression is `Limit:\s+(.*)\s+` you'd only get a match if the line after `Source Template:` begins with `Limit:`.

Basically, the pattern `Source Template:\s+(.*)\s+` only matches this:

```
...
                        \\SERVER\DirA\SubdirA\SubdirA1
Source Template:        TemplateA (Matches template)
Quota Status:           Enabled
Limit:                  500.00 MB (Hard)
...
```

when you actually need it to match this:

```
...
                        \\SERVER\DirA\SubdirA\SubdirA1
Source Template:        TemplateA (Matches template)
Quota Status:           Enabled
Limit:                  500.00 MB (Hard)
...
```

To make it include additional lines you need to change

```
'Source Template:\s+(.*)\s+'
```

into

```
'Source Template:\s+(.*)[\s\S]+?'
```

The character class `[\s\S]` matches any character instead of just whitespace characters (`\s`), and the modifier `+?` makes an non-greedy match of one or more characters. That way the expression includes all text up to the next occurrence of the string `Limit:`.

Comment: OK now it makes sense. I thought `.*` would match all characters up to the next string, but from what I'm seeing it stops matching at new line?

Comment: `.` matches any character *except newlines*, `*` modifies the previous expression to match zero or more times.

Answer (score 0):

- I recently read in an answer that the validity of the $matches
  collection over pipe boundaries isn't guarantied.
- Therefor I removed the where,
- get the data from file
- A new second RegEx is used to split the file into chunks starting
  with (and including) `Quota Path`)
- I broke down the RegEx in RegEx101.com see link.
- and use named capture groups to better keep track
- the resulting $objArr is piped to Out-Gridview

---

```
# https://www.regex101.com/r/3WrfYk/1
$File = ".\quota.txt"
# dirquota qu l | Set-Content $File
$Delimiter = 'Quota Path:'
$Escaped   = [regex]::Escape($Delimiter)
$Split     = "(?!^)(?=$Escaped)"
$RegEx = '(?smi)^Quota Path:\s+(?<QuotaPath>.*?)$.*?' `
         + '^Source Template:\s+(?<Template>.*?)$.*?' `
         + '^Limit:\s+(?<QuotaLimit>.*?)' `
         + 'Used:\s+(?<Used>.*?)$.' `
         + 'Available:\s+(?<Available>.*?)$.'
$objArr = @()
$objArr = ((Get-Content $File -Raw) -split $Split)|
  foreach {
    if ($_ -match $RegEx) {
       New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property (
       [ordered]@{ QuotaPath  = $matches.QuotaPath 
                   Template   = $matches.Template  
                   QuotaLimit = $matches.QuotaLimit
                   Used       = $matches.Used      
                   Availble   = $matches.Availble   
                })
    } # if
} # foreach
$objArr|select QuotaPath,Template,QuotaLimit,Used,Available|out-gridview
```

Comment: The problem is with the OP's regular expression, not with `$matches`. Also, he's using Server 2008 R2, which ships with PowerShell v2. Unless he upgraded to PowerShell v3 or newer `Get-Content -Raw` won't work for him.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I've upgraded all of our 2008 R2 servers to PS 4.0.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Since I fidled with the RegEx I'm very well aware that it got messed up : thats why I mentioned RegEx101.com which is quite helpful seeing the RE fails at one point with `catastophic backtracking`.